# C++ "error: multiple types in one declaration" and "error: expected initializer before 'KeyType'"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks

When I run the following code...

```
#ifndef KEYEDITEM_H_INCLUDED
#define KEYEDITEM_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

typedef std::string KeyType;

class KeyedItem {
    public:
        KeyedItem() {}
        KeyedItem(const KeyType& keyValue) : searchKey(keyValue) {}
        KeyType getKey() const
        { return searchKey;
        }

    private:
        KeyType searchKey; };

#endif // KEYEDITEM_H_INCLUDED
```

I get an error message "error: expected initializer before 'KeyType'"

I thought at first that this could be related to the declaring the string type so I changed it to the following to see if it would work...

```
#ifndef KEYEDITEM_H_INCLUDED
#define KEYEDITEM_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>
//typedef std::string KeyType;

class KeyedItem
{
    public:
        KeyedItem() {}
        KeyedItem(const std::string& keyValue) : searchKey(keyValue) {}
        std::string getKey() const
        { return searchKey;
        }

    private:
        std::string searchKey;
};

#endif // KEYEDITEM_H_INCLUDED
```

but I got the error "error: multiple types in one declaration" I have looked for errors for both of these errors and have found nothing that helps. I have gone over the class to make sure I have semi-colons where needed and I seem to have all of them.

I don't have a implementation file simply because I didn't need one, but could that be the problem?

This is just a class for a binary search tree. I am working in CodeBlocks using the GNU GCC compiler.

TreeNode.h

```
#ifndef TREENODE_H_INCLUDED
#define TREENODE_H_INCLUDED

#include "KeyedItem.h"

typedef KeyedItem TreeItemType;

class TreeNode
{
    private:
        TreeNode() {}
        TreeNode(const TreeItemType& nodeItem,
                 TreeNode *left = NULL,
                 TreeNode *right = NULL) : item(nodeItem), leftChildPtr(left), rightChildPtr(right) {}

        TreeItemType item;
        TreeNode *leftChildPtr, *rightChildPtr;

        friend class BinarySearchTree;
};

#endif // TREENODE_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: Is this all your code? Does anything else reference this code? If I just copy and paste your first snippet and compile it a `main` function that uses a `KeyedItem`, my code compiles fine.

Comment: No, this is just the KeyedItem class. I have the "KeyedItem.h" included in another header named "TreeNode.h" and "TreeNode.h" is included in another header named "BinarySearchTree.h"

Comment: I solved it. Turns out I was missing a header include in my main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved... Turns out I was missing a header include in my main.

Answer (score 1):

you need to compile with g++ not gcc